# Do we need to write UI test case for Login?

Tags: ios, xctest, xctestcase

Question :

While writing UI Test cases for app do i need to write test case for login also ?

Already Done :
 As currently i have written test cases for various scenarios but if i Will not login in app and run the test cases then all my test cases get Failed.

I don't understand what to do?

Let me know any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your app depends on the user being logged in, then yes. To clarify : are the scenarios (screens) reachable with a logged out user? Also, in an ideal world everything should be covered by tests.

Comment: In my app i am showing user a login screen for the first time only, now if user is logged in then i am not showing that screen again. Login user can logout and can login with other emails.

So in above case how i can check that is login done or not ? And if i run all my test with cmd + U then it run all UI test randomly. so how i can check that my login test should run first ?

Comment: @Losiowaty In an ideal world, no tests would be necessary. And I wouldn't write software. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so (from the comments) it is needed for the user to be logged in. So you should at least check in your tests if there is a user logged in and if not, then login on. Also, the login process itself should be tested.

Ideally, your each test case should begin with a logged out user and end in this state. So each would look like this :

1. Login user
2. Perform the actual test
3. Logout user

This way you test the whole flow of a feature in your app.

Comment: Thank you so much for this work around.